# Expression depeding on Jenkins build boolean parameter doesn't work in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've inherited some Jenkins pipeline and try to improve it. Jenkins and groovy is quite fresh topic for me, so most probably I'm doing something wrong.
I'm using `Jenkins ver. 2.121.3`

Main aim was to add build parameter to do some extra cleaning during build. So I've added parameter `CLEAN_FIRST` with Boolean type and default value `false` to a job configuration and did something like this in pipeline:

```
// CLEAN_FIRST = false
// def prefix = CLEAN_FIRST ? "" : "REM"

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Some step') {
            steps {
                script {
                    node('master') {
                        cleanWs()
                        try {
                            def prefix = CLEAN_FIRST ? "" : "REM"
                            echo "CLEAN_FIRST=$CLEAN_FIRST prefix=$prefix"
                            bat (label: 'build third party',
                                script: """
                                $prefix call cleanSomthing.bat
                                call doOtherStuff.bat
                                """
                        } finally {
                            echo "some stuff"
                        }
                    } // node
                } // script 
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

Now this doesn't work as expected. "REM" prefix is not added.

Echo prints:

```
CLEAN_FIRST=false prefix=
```

And `bat` invokes `cleanSomthing.bat` which I wish to avoid (to save on build times).

I've tried to make `prefix` global, but with same result.

Most probably this is caused by some evaluation order or scoping issue, but I can't put finger on it.

Can someone give me a clue why it doesn't work? How to fix it?

---

Answered own question. Is this problem fixed on some version of Jenkins?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `def` keyword?

Comment: AFAIK `def` makes variable local, but will try it (waits in build queue).

Comment: @DibakarAditya as expected: same result

Comment: I get the expected result `CLEAN_FIRST=false prefix=REM` and `C:\jenkins\workspace\test-pipeline>REM call cleanSomthing.bat ` with the same Pipeline code that you have posted above and after uncommenting `CLEAN_FIRST = false` at the top. I am on Jenkins 2.150.2 and Pipeline: Groovy Plugin 2.70.

Comment: Thanks for feedback I've found root cause of the problem :). I'm using `Jenkins ver. 2.121.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found source of problems. It is a bit funny.

When running this pipeline (tested on Mac machine since it had empty job queue):

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Some step') {
            steps {
                script {
                    node('Mac') {
                        cleanWs()
                        try {
                            def logic = true
                            def prefix = CLEAN_FIRST ? "Ole" : "REM"
                            def typeLogic = logic.getClass()
                            def typeParam = CLEAN_FIRST.getClass()

                            echo "typeLogic=$typeLogic typeParam=$typeParam"
                            echo "CLEAN_FIRST=$CLEAN_FIRST prefix=$prefix"
                            sh (script: """
                            echo prefix=$prefix
                            """)
                        } finally {
                            echo "some stuff"
                        }
                    } // node
                } // script 
            } // steps
        } // stage
    } // stages
} // pipeline
```

I've got this outcome:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Some step)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/EIbuild_MacOS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] echo
typeLogic=class java.lang.Boolean typeParam=class java.lang.String
[Pipeline] echo
CLEAN_FIRST=false prefix=Ole
[Pipeline] sh
[EIbuild_MacOS] Running shell script
+ echo prefix=Ole
prefix=Ole
[Pipeline] echo
some stuff
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So now source the problem is obvious.
Jenkins in configuration promises variable of type `Boolean`, but in fact provides type `String` with values are `"true"` or `"false"` which are always evaluated as `true` when used as condition since both values are not empty strings :).

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
def prefix = CLEAN_FIRST ? "" : "REM"
```

with

```
def prefix = params.CLEAN_FIRST ? "" : "REM"
```

Comment: I will try that. Note that in all other contexts build parameters are working fin without `params.`, so why this should fix anything?

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is not that. I've found root cause (see my answer).